# Change permissions on Google Drive folder to work with Apache htdocs

Tags: google-drive-api, access-denied, htdocs

I want to use my Google Drive as a common place to store my websites that get run through apache. I downloaded the Google Drive client and copied my htdocs folder there. I then put a shortcut to this folder where the old htdocs would go. Now when I go to a development site I get greeted with an Access Forbidden! error. Is there a way to change the permissions on this folder or is the whole approach flawed?

Comment: This appears to be a common issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/fUuPbRZsIb0

Answer (score 0):

The quick way around this is to chmod the folder you're trying to access and any dependencies inside it. I used 755 and recursively applied it to the files inside my project's www folder but you'll likely have to chmod the parent folder even further up using 755.

```
chmod 755 -R www
```

If you can't figure out where to apply the permissions changes to, you can read your Apache error logs. I use this command:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

That should get you sorted out.